# Difference between Gnome-MPV and MPV-player

Tags: 18.04, mpv-media-player

Both Gnome-MPV and MPV player share the name MPV. So what is the difference between them?

Comment: Do you have any link fof `MPV-player`?

Comment: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/12/install-mpv-0-28-0-in-ubuntu-18-04-16-04/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

mpv is media player software, based on MPlayer and mplayer2. It has a simple GUI itself, and you can install it using:

```
sudo apt install mpv
```

it's the main project, however there are people trying to create a better and more exciting GUI for mpv based on GTK+ so it matches gnome desktop and its tools, so basically: GNOME MPV is a simple GTK+ frontend for mpv. GNOME MPV interacts with mpv via the client API exported by libmpv, allowing access to mpv's powerful playback capabilities.

mpv: the main project which provides all capabilities also known as mpv player.
gnome mpv: uses mpv as its internal.

[GNOME MPV](https://github.com/gnome-mpv/gnome-mpv)
[MPV](https://mpv.io/)